# How to stop regex at the first match (non greedy search)

Tags: regex

I want to find all occurrences of freeWifi = "Y" and state = "NY" in the a json string but if there 2 consecutive occurences it consider them as one match instead of 2:

The pattern I used is '"freeWifi": "Y",(\s+\S+)+state": "NY"'.

When I use '"freeWifi": "Y",(\s+\S+){5}state": "NY"' it gives me the desired solution but it is not general enough in case the new lines are added to the json file.

Part of the data:

```
     "freeWifi": "Y", 
    "storeNumber": "14372", 
    "phone": "(305)672-7055", 
    "state": "NY", 
    "storeUrl": "http://www.mcflorida.com/14372", 
    "playplace": "N", 
    "address": "1601 ALTON RD", 
    "storeType": "FREESTANDING", 
    "archCard": "Y", 
    "driveThru": "Y"
  }
  "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": {
    "city": "MIAMI", 
    "zip": "33135", 
    "freeWifi": "Y", 
    "storeNumber": "7408", 
    "phone": "(305)285-0974", 
    "state": "NY", 
    "storeUrl": "http://www.mcflorida.com/7408", 
    "playplace": "Y", 
    "address": "1400 SW 8TH ST", 
    "storeType": "FREESTANDING", 
    "archCard": "Y", 
    "driveThru": "Y"
  }
}, 
{
```

Part II

After implementing Steven solution, when I tried it on the data file with many entries, the program ran forever and did not give an answer.

The new regex is:  '"freeWifi": "Y",(\s+?\S+?)+?state": "NY"'.

To see why the system hangs I checked the program against part of the data, increasing the size by 100,000 bytes each time. The results shows significant slowdown as the size increases' showing possibly problem of the regex, as explained in  [Program run forever when matching regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235854/program-run-forever-when-matching-regex).

Sorry for the lousy display of the table, but I could not make it nicer (I removed tabs and padded with spaces but it ignores them)

Time_Passed.....Size_Checked     File_Size    Matches
7.3e-05 ...........100000         8345167        30
0.008906         200000         8345167        30
0.466485         300000         8345167        31
0.500054         400000         8345167        75
0.523969         500000         8345167        142
0.553361         600000         8345167        201
0.586032         700000         8345167        201
1.072181         800000         8345167        338
1.114541         900000         8345167        482
1.157304         1000000        8345167        630
1.203889         1100000        8345167        630
1.625656         1200000        8345167        630
3.126974         1300000        8345167        630
6.501044         1400000        8345167        630
12.476704        1500000        8345167        630

Comment: Thanks Steven. Your solution works, theoretically

.But when I tried it on the data file with many entries, the program ran forever and did not give an answer

Comment: To see why the system hangs I checked the program against part of the data, increasing the size by 100,000 bytes each time. The results shows significant slowdown as the size increases' showing possibly problem of the regex, as explained in .

Answer (score 1):

The [lazy operator](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) is `?`.  Your expression with the lazy operator would be `"freeWifi": "Y",(\s+?\S+?)+state": "NY"` See example in [regexr](https://regexr.com/5h9c9).

As @anubhava has pointed out, this is not going to work on generic input. For example I imagine that you don't want this match:

```
  "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": {
    "freeWifi": "Y", 
    "storeNumber": "9876", 
    "state": "PA"
  }
},
  "type": "Feature", 
  "properties": {
    "freeWifi": "N", 
    "storeNumber": "1234", 
    "state": "NY", 
     }
},
```